# How can I make a repeater field editable?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a page with a repeater.. I have to make some fields of this one editable. I don't see how I can transform the repeater label into a textbox.. Can I use jquery to do that?

Have somebody make this kind of manipulation?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Repeater control does not have an EditTemplate like many of the other data controls.

I would suggest having the edit fields either in a hidden Placeholder, then show this when clicking an edit button. This would involve the page posting back and then you having to show/hide the relevant parts in the `ItemCommand` handler.

Another way would be do add the edit fields/textboxs in a Panel control, then hide this through `display: none;`. Then you can change this to `display: block;` with some javascript. This will avoid the page PostBack.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a Repeater, but a DataList control is more straightforward and is just as easy to use.  There's an MSDN article on doing it in a Datalist control with full source code here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf5211wb(v=vs.71).aspx

Converting a repeater to a DataList is a much easier approach than having editable items in a Repeater.

HOWEVER

to answer your question directly, there IS a Codeproject sample here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/EditableRepeater.aspx

that shows how to use a Repeater with full edit functionality (including adding and deleting items).

To see the relevant code in the CodePlex article, search for the text "EditIndex".  The relevant code-behind is always a few lines above and/or below this keyword.

Comment: Seems like a lot of code for nothing really. Easier and cleaner just to create an edit page and link to that from the repeater.

Comment: I agree.  I think that's why I and @Samich, suggested using an alternative control to the Repeater instead as our first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to do this:

1. using standart control probably you need GridView.
2. You can define the template for repeater and put TextBox there, then
   on postback you will need to find dynamically created controls and
   also you will need to take care to keep ID's of these controls the
   same on postbacks.
3. And the other thing - you can replace label with the textBox using
   jQuery and then update value via Ajax reques.

You decide what you need :) Anyway it's a lot of samples in the internet.