# How to update the value in the repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a repeater that already has values like this:

[image]

I need to allow the users to enter price for the corresponding ITEM and i need to update the values to ITEM table in the database.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The Repeater control does not have an EditTemplate like many of the other data controls.

I would suggest having the edit fields either in a hidden Placeholder, then show this when clicking an edit button. This would involve the page posting back and then you having to show/hide the relevant parts in the ItemCommand handler.

Another way would be do add the edit fields/textboxs in a Panel control, then hide this through display: none;. Then you can change this to display: block; with some javascript. This will avoid the page PostBack.

Reference : [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270993/how-can-i-make-a-repeater-field-editable)